# Jquery, increment/decrease values not past "0"

Tags: jquery, increment, counting, decrement

So I am working on something, and not quite the best way to approach this.

I have some elements, and basically when a list item is clicked, it adds a value to a div element.

when the other list item is clicked, the siblings value should decrease, but not exceed 0 (ie. -1, -2, -3)

Im just not sure the most logical, easiest way to write that.

```
percentage = $("#percent1");
percentage2 = $("#percent2");
nCircleA = 0;
nCircleB = 0;

$('ul li.first').on('click', function() {
    circle1();
});
$('ul li.second').on('click', function() {
    circle2();
});

function circle1() {
    percentage.html(++nCircleA);
    percentage2.html(--nCircleB);
}

function circle2() {
    percentage2.html(++nCircleB);
    percentage.html(--nCircleA);
}

circle1();
circle2();
```

see [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GregWebBandit/uXaks/)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this would do what you need

```
nCircleA -1 < 0 ? 0 : --nCircleA
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NVJjb/)

Comment: @gregdsign this is a short hand if statement , and no need to change the positive value as it will never be negative if you add .